# Chrome always restart a previous completed download on startup

Tags: google-chrome

Why is my version of Chrome always restart the download of a finished file after startup?

I've tried to open the files to tell chrome "Hey I have used this file. It's all okay" but after a restart of Chrome the download starts over again.

Someone have a constructive answer?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean you are downloading an update or a file?

Comment: @Dave I am talking about a file.

Comment: @Snickbrack Maybe you have a tab with a url pointing to the download link, and so every time you open Chrome it opens this tab and begins the download again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in the comments by [Atzmon](https://superuser.com/users/589157/atzmon)

> Maybe you have a tab with a url pointing to the download link, and so every time you open Chrome it opens this tab and begins the download again